# Is it advisable to format namenode each time before running jps?

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, bigdata

I have successfully installed Hadoop. But When I start all daemons and run jps, I am unable to see the namenode. However, If I format the namenode using the command hadoop namenode -format, I can see the namenode while running jps. Is it advisable to format namenode each time before running jps ?. Is there any other way this could be avoided so that I can see my namenode daemon without formatting it every time. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you,
Gautham

Comment: Check out for any error in name node log? There is **no need** to format every time.

Comment: Where Can i find the namenode log ?. And what am i supposed to do when I get there ?

Comment: grep for ERROR in $HADOOP_HOME/logs/*namenode*

Comment: Formatting the namenode removes all of your data. Once the cluster is running, you should have no need to reformat it ever again. As mentioned, check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the namenode needs to be formatted everytime beofre you start the daemons unless you have not overriddden the hdfs configurations dfs.name.dir , dfs.data.dir. By default it points to /tmp directory which will be cleared when your machine restarts.
You can surely avoid it.You have to change this from /tmp to another location in your home directory by overriding these values in your hdfs-site.xml file located in your HADOOP configuration directory.

Do the following steps

Create a directory in your home directory for keeping namenode image & datanode blocks (Replace with your login name)

```
mkdir /home/<USER>/pseudo/
```

Modify your hdfs-site.xml file in your HADOOP_CONF_DIR(hadoop configuration direcotry) as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/<USER>/pseudo/dfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:///home/<USER>/pseudo/dfs/data</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Format your hdfs namenode & start using